# Is it really possible for a liquid to stay afloat a gas (vapor)?

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics

I have a book at home called [Chemical Thermodynamics for Process Simulation](https://www.wiley.com/en-us/Chemical+Thermodynamics+for+Process+Simulation,+2nd,+Completely+Revised+and+Enlarged+Edition-p-9783527343256) (I have the first edition) and at the very beginning of chapter 2 of the book one may read the following:

[image: CO2-water system at high pressure]

No reference is given. I have never found anything about it so far and I am curious to know whether this statement is true.

Comment: Yes, supercritical liquid may have higher density then liquid.

Comment: The crucial point is that CO2 at high pressure, and moderately above room temperature, becomes a super critical fluid and not a gas.

Comment: The difference between a liquid and a gas is not as clearcut as the question implies.

Comment: There is no fundamental reason why a not yet supercritical gas cannot also have a higer density than some liquid at the same conditions, is there?

Comment: @Karl There isn't, but even in different conditions that would be rather extreme example.

Comment: The critical temperature of CO2 is 35C.  Above this temperature, no matter high the pressure, CO2 can't be liquified.  So it is certainly possible to find a pressure where its density is higher than that of water.

Comment: @ChetMiller Water in normal state - sure. Water under equally high pressure - not necessarily; it's density is also getting higher and later it turns into "hot ice" phases.

Comment: Density of liquid water just below the critical point ( cca 374 Deg C )  is near 0.2 g/mL. I suppose it is possible to compress gaseous CO2 at this temperature above this density. OTOH, hard to a priory tell, how CO2 dissolution in water affects the density and phase thermodynamics.

Answer (score 1):

Yes! Here's a video of Cody floating NaK (liquid) or ethanol/water (liquid) on compressed xenon (gas):
https://youtu.be/AsP4yMY-a6U